# Highcharts Categories Bug?

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I am building a live sales board which automatically updates a column chart showing new sales numbers for a team of agents.

I have a function, updateChart() which does the following:

- iterates through the sales object and pulls keys into an array (to be used for categories)
- if newCategories.length is less than the current categories length, point.remove(); the extra number of points
- else, if newCategories length is longer, series.addPoint(0); a number of new points to each series to make room for the new data
- alphabetically sort newCategories
- setCategories(newCategories)
- loop through all points in each series and update with new y-values

The example starts with 2 categories (2 people) and their sales numbers.  The first update removes one of the agents (they deleted their sale), then the next update adds them back (they add their sale back).

After the second update, the second person's category isn't their name, it's the number "2".  I even console.log the xAxis categories right before (or after) the chart.redraw() method and it logs the correct categories.

The JS fiddle below shows exactly this issue.

**(Edit, fiddle had JS error before, issue is now shown)**

http://jsfiddle.net/t3y6h/1/

For reference, here is the updateChart() function:

```
//this function updates the chart in the current view. it does not redraw the entire chart,
//it updates points and adds/removes x-axis items when needed
function updateChart()
{
    var chart = $("#teamboard").highcharts();
    var sales = getSalesObject();

    //place all categories (keys) of sales object into an array
    var newCategories = [];
    for(var s in sales)
    {
        newCategories.push(s);
    }

    //remove extra data points from end of series if there are less categories now
    //this loop will not run if newCategories is the same length or greater
    for(var i = newCategories.length; i < chart.xAxis[0].categories.length; i++)
    {
        for(var j = 0; j < chart.series.length; j++)
        {
            chart.series[j].data[i].remove(false);
        }
    }

    //if there are more new categories, we need to add that new data points to the end of the series
    for(var i = chart.xAxis[0].categories.length; i < newCategories.length; i++)
    {
        for(var j = 0; j < chart.series.length; j++)
        {
            //temporarily add 0, we will go and update every point later
            chart.series[j].addPoint(0, false);
        }
    }

    //alphabetically sort the x-Axis
    newCategories.sort();

    //assign the new sorted categories to the x-Axis
    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(newCategories);

    //loop through all categories and update cable, internet, phone
    for(var i = 0; i < newCategories.length; i++)
    {
        chart.series[0].data[i].update(sales[newCategories[i]].cable, false);
        chart.series[1].data[i].update(sales[newCategories[i]].internet, false);
        chart.series[2].data[i].update(sales[newCategories[i]].phone, false);
    }

    chart.redraw();
}
```

Example sales object:

```
{'Bart':{cable:4, internet:5, phone:5}, 'Andy':{cable:1, internet:1, phone:1}}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably caused by ongoing animation, and trying to update points, so something is missing there.

Proper way to achieve that is to use setData instead. Fixed example: http://jsfiddle.net/t3y6h/5/

```
function updateChart() {
    var chart = $("#container").highcharts();
    var sales = getSalesObject(salesObjectNumber++),
        sorter = [],        // temporary container for sorting data
        d = [[],[],[]];     // temporary data point container


    //place all categories (keys) of sales object into an array
    var newCategories = [];
    for (var s in sales) {
        sorter.push([s, sales[s]]);
    }

    sorter.sort(function(a, b) {
       return a[0] > b[0];  
    });

    //place all categories (keys) of sales object into an array
    var newCategories = [];
    for (var s in sorter) {
        newCategories.push(sorter[s][0]);
        d[0].push(sorter[s][1].cable);
        d[1].push(sorter[s][1].internet);
        d[2].push(sorter[s][1].phone);
    }
    //assign the new sorted categories to the x-Axis
    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(newCategories, false);

    //loop through all categories and update cable, internet, phone
    for (var i = 0; i < newCategories.length; i++) {
        chart.series[0].setData(d[0], false);
        chart.series[1].setData(d[1], false);
        chart.series[2].setData(d[2], false);
    }
    //log categories, apparently they were set correctly?
    $("#log").append(chart.xAxis[0].categories + '<br />');

    chart.redraw();
}
```

**EDIT:**

Another solution is to add point with specified x-value, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/t3y6h/6/

Code:

```
    //if there are more new categories, we need to add that new data points to the end of the series
    for(var i = chart.xAxis[0].categories.length; i < newCategories.length; i++)
    {
        for(var j = 0; j < chart.series.length; j++)
        {
            //temporarily add 0, we will go and update every point later
            chart.series[j].addPoint([i, 0], false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Pawel. This drops the animation component though which we are trying to keep. If we didn't care about that, it would be much easier to just disable animation and redraw the whole chart from scratch.